# Bit shifting not shifting correctly?

Tags: c, long-integer, bit-shift, unsigned, 8051

I am programming the 8051 in C using the Si Labs IDE. I currently have three bytes: `address_byte3, address_byte2, and address_byte1`. I then initialized a variable `address_sum` to be an `unsigned long int` then did the following operation on it...

```
address_sum=(address_byte3<<16)+(address_byte2<<8)+(address_byte1);
```

This operation would lead me to believe that the value loaded into `address_sum` if `address_byte3, address_byte2, & address_byte1` were `0x92, 0x56, & 0x78`, respectively, would be `0xXX925678`. Instead I am getting a value of `0xXX005678`. My logic seems sound but then again I am the one writing the code so I'm biased and could be blinded by my own ignorance. Does anyone have a solution or an explanation as to why the value for `address_byte` is "lost"?

Thank you.

Comment: How wide is `int` on your system? It is likely to be 16 bits. And the arithmetic is done with operands promoted to `int`, so shifting by `16` will give you a nice zero...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Shifting by 16 will give you _undefined behavior_

Comment: 8051 appears to be the "Intel_MCS-51", which has 8-bit registers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51

Comment: @MooingDuck It depends on the value of `address_byte3` http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4 But yeah. UB in the absolute majority of cases (except `address_byte3=0`.)

Comment: Hi, yes `int` value is 2 bytes wide. I was not aware that my char variables would be promoted to an `int` upon operations.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Shifting an 16 bit `int` by 16 invokes undefined behaviour, that's not a matter of "majority" or the original value. Even for a smaller shiftcount, it will invoke UB if the sign is shifted. There is no guarantee it will be `0`.

Comment: @JaimePerez: That's basic C knowledge. You really should read about integer promotions and inform about other pitfalls of the language!

Comment: @Olaf i will make sure to buff up on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables shorter than `int` are promoted to `int` when doing calculations on them. It seems that your `int` type is 16-bit, so shifting it by 16 bits doesn't work right.

You should explicitly cast the variables to the result type (`unsigned long`):

```
address_sum = ((unsigned long)address_byte3<<16) +
              ((unsigned long)address_byte2<<8) +
              (unsigned long)address_byte1;
```

The last casting is superfluous but doesn't hurt.

Comment: Care should be take in case the bytes are actually `signed char`

Comment: This worked and just about solved every other bug I was seeing in my code. Thank you. I was not aware that my `char` variables would be promoted to an `int`. So casting it would prevent me from losing any of my bits when doing bitwise op on them? Also, I am casting this inside a routine so does that mean that this will only happen in the routine and the variable will not be affected in the `main()`?

Comment: Casting does not affect the casted variable.

Comment: I would put extra parens to visually enforce that the cast is applied to the variable before shifting not after, even if there is an order of operations rule...

Answer (score 1):

A shift of a 16-bit `int/unsigned`, as well explained by [@anatolyg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43377042/2410359) will only result in a 16-bit answer.

I avoid casting, as a general promotion scheme, as sometimes it may *narrow* the result as code evolves over time and the maintainer uses wider operands.

Alternatives:

`((type_of_target) 1) *`: This will insure each operation is *at least* the width of the target.

```
unsigned long address_sum;
...
address_sum = (1UL*address_byte3<<16) + (1UL*address_byte2<<8) + address_byte1;
```

Assign to the destination and then operate:

```
address_sum = address_byte3;
address_sum = address_sum << 8 + address_byte2;
address_sum = address_sum << 8 + address_byte1;
```

A sneaky, thought not pleasant looking 1-line alternative.  Recall `* +` higher order precedence than shift

```
address_sum = (0*address_sum + address_byte3 << 16) + 
              (0*address_sum + address_byte2 <<  8) + address_byte1;
```

---

Consider [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376973/bit-shifting-not-shifting-correctly/43377446#comment73816498_43377042) concern and use 8-bit unsigned "bytes".

Answer (score 0):

My preference is a variation on chux

bigger declaration address;
byte declaration a,b,c;

```
address =a; address<<=8;
address|=b; address<<=8;
address|=c;
```

Despite being the most verbose all of the answers thus far should optimize into basically the same code.  But would have to test the specific compiler to see.  Can the 8051 shift more than one bit at a time per instruction anyway?  Dont remember.

Comment: Yes you can shift more than one bit per instruction. I am sure that that is what you are doing in your example above My problem was that I was unaware that my variables were being promoted to and int and when I shifted by 16 bits the uppermost were lost thus giving me undefined behavior.

Comment: I am talking about the instruction set some instruction sets the shift instruction is one bit at a time and you have to call the instruction many times.  I have experienced so many instruction sets I dont remember the nuances of every single one that I havent used in a few years...the 8051 comes from the era of one bit per shift, but the 8086 is a similar era and has a multibit shift option.

Comment: yeah it uses a one bit shift per instruction (rlc or rrc basically), but since the registers are 8 bits, shifting wouldnt actually happen here, registers would likely not be used either but three memory locations, and I dont know what you would be using a 24 bit address with, but that is another story...